# EmberJS: Customize the REST URL of a related model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, adapter

In the [Ember Documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/), it mentions this:

> An adapter is an object that knows about your particular server
>   backend and is responsible for translating requests for and changes to
>   records into the appropriate calls to your server.
>
> For example, if your application asks for a person record with an ID
>   of 1, how should Ember Data load it? Is the URL /person/1 or /resources/people/1?

In my example, I have a `User` model with related `Messages`.  When the Ember store retrieves related messages for a user, it generates a query in the form `/messages/?ids=18` using something like this:

```
user = this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
user.get('messages');
```

I'd like to load these messages with a URL like `/users/2/messages/`.

I looked through Ember's documentation on adapters and wasn't able to find anything to implement this specifically.  How do I customize the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a message adapter that builds the right url for the end point.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({

  find: function(store, type, id) {
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, id), 'GET');
  },

  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record, { includeId: true });
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, null), "POST", {data: data});
  },

  buildURL: function(type, id) {
    var url = [],
        host = Ember.get(this, 'host'),
        prefix = this.urlPrefix(),
        user_id = this.container.lookup('controller:user').get('id');

    // append user and id to the url
    url.push('users/' + user_id);

    if (type) { url.push(this.pathForType(type)); }
    if (id) { url.push(id); }

    if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url) { url = '/' + url; }

    return url;
  }

});
```

I hope this is helpful.

Cheers